# Lightbox scrolling issue with IE7 & 8

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

The lightbox that i am using works great with all browsers except for IE. In IE, its giving me triple scrolls.

http://obliqueinteractive.com/demo/monster/

CSS code for the iframe:

```
#wrap {
float:left;
width:800px;
height:500px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
#content-wrap {
float:left;
width:700px;
padding-left:50px;
}
```

Why is IE adding additional scrolls to the lightbox window? any suggestions?

Comment: FYI: there're two scroll bars in the box when it's run in Chrome.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the issue in my IE8? Although your site did pretty much crash my browser. Also that's FancyBox not LightBox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading content via iframe, why not load it via AJAX? This would mean that there would be no scroll bars as the lightbox can resize to fit the content. You can optionally set a width of the lightbox to restrict the width and let the height be automatic

From the [documentation](http://fancybox.net/howto):

```
<a href="http://www.example/data.php">This takes content using ajax</a>
```